# Cassandra Best Practice for Deleting Large Amounts of Rows

Tags: cassandra

I'm curious how people handle deletion of large numbers of rows. We had an outage thanks to a combination of deleting a million+ rows, tombstones, auto-compaction/30 second long GCs. I would like to avoid that in the future...

Comment: Yeah, the whole "delete" thing isn't that great in Cassandra - due to what you're mentioning. If you have Time Series data (basically insert once, leave it alone, and eventually delete the rows), TWCS with TTLs is by far the best way to handle these. I'm not sure if you have this type of data, but if you do, I highly recommend it. Do you have to do these large sets of deletes at once, frequently?

Comment: We generally do very few deletes, however one of our devs had a runaway process - he created millions of rows. We're still trying to clean up that mess.

Comment: Do you have to delete at all?

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete different ways, depending on you schema (in priority order, from best to worse):

- truncate table
- delete by partition key - `delete from ks.table where pk = id`
- delete by range - `delete from ks.table where pk = id and c1 > val1 and c1 < val2`
- delete rows - delete from ks.table where pk = id and c1 = val1 and c2 = val2 ...`
- delete individual cells - delete col1, col2 where pk = id ....`